# vscode sidebar: is it possible hide to `maven`, `spring-boot`, etc for non Java projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Java extensions like `maven`, `spring-board`, `Java`, etc.
And vscode shows-up these extensions all the time in side-bar like in attached screen-shot.

[image: VSCODE Side-Bar]

Is it possible to items like `JAVA PROJECTS`, `MAVEN`, `SPRING-BOOT DASHBOARD` when I work on non-Java projects (like when I open a Python project)

I know that I can hide them manually by clicking on `...` at top-right.
Want to know if I can get this done automatically.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The team is actually doing such works right now, I believe some of them will be available very soon. Here are some issue links:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/549
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/issues/372
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/793